# topology and filter theory

Tags: general-topology, filters

Given $X$ is topological space and $F$ is filter of $X$, is it true that $X\in F$? i've learned about filter but i still don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one axiom for a filter is that filters are non-empty, so some $A \subseteq X$ exists with $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

Another is that $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $A \subseteq B$ imply $B \in \mathcal{F}$ (filters are closed under enlargements) and as $A \subseteq X$ is trivial, $X \in \mathcal{F}$ follows, for *any* filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$.

Comment: Just realize that statement, thank you! finally i get it

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By definition, a filter $\cal F$ is non-empty and is upward-closed. Thus $\cal F$ contains at least a subset $E$ of $X$, and since $E \subseteq X$, $X \in {\cal F}$.

Comment: just realize that statement, thank you!